# Run azure as local to test control

Tags: c#, azure, user-controls

Ok. So I'm not sure the title is the best description for my question.

Here's the problem. I have a web app that is running on MS Windows Azure. To test it, Visual Studio uses an Azure Emulator. I have found a 3rd party control that I would like to use on my site. The company allows you to download a demo of the control so that you can test it in your site before purchasing a license. This control is in the form of a dll, but inside of that DLL is also code that blocks anything other than pages running locally from being able to load the control. Since I am using Windows Azure emulator to test, everything 'appears' to not be local to the dll, hence I cannot test it. I have tried contacting the company but no response yet. Any idea's that would maybe let me make Azure appear to be local when I am debugging locally so that I can test it?

This is not a means to get around purchasing the control, but simply allowing me to make sure it works before purchasing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to do the following:

1. Deploy your application to a Cloud Service (Web Role)
2. Make sure you enable remote desktop
3. Connect through remote desktop to your instance
4. Open Internet Explorer and navigate to "http://localhost". This will allow you to do some functional testing, but you won't be able to test if it supports a web farm (multiple instances).

But it really depends what 'local' means to the assembly. Does this simply mean doing a request on "http://localhost"? Or do you need to run your web application in Cassini?